# Click on specific element in UICollectionViewCell not called(instead ItemSelected fired from Source) Xamarin.ios

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I have a CollectionView in my Xamarin.iOS projet. I've a button inside my UICollectionViewCell and I'd like to have TouchDown on my button.

But when I click on this button, ItemSelected fired and not my TouchDown event handler (the global touch on cell called instead of specific touch).

Could you help me how can I do specify my touch inside any cells pls ? (sorry for my English which is not top)

here is an ex of my code :

```
class MyCollectionViewSource : UICollectionViewSource
{
    List<string> _Datas;

    public MyCollectionViewSource(List<string> datas)
    {
        _Datas = datas;
    }

    public override nint GetItemsCount(UICollectionView collectionView, nint section)
    {
        return _Datas.Count;
    }

    public override UICollectionViewCell GetCell(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {

        var view = (MyCollectionViewCell)collectionView.DequeueReusableCell(MyCollectionViewCell.CellId, indexPath);
        return view;
    }

    public override void ItemSelected(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Row {0} selected", indexPath.Row);
    }

    public override bool ShouldSelectItem(UICollectionView collectionView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        return true;
    }
}

class MyCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell
{
    UIView _MyCellView;

    public static readonly NSString CellId = new NSString("MyCollectionViewCell");

    [Export("initWithFrame:")]
    MyCollectionViewCell(RectangleF frame) : base(frame)
    {
        _MyCellView = new UIView();
        ContentView.AddSubview(_MyCellView);

        UIButton btn = new UIButton();
        btn.SetTitle("test", UIControlState.Normal);
        btn.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0, 100, 20);
        btn.TouchDown += Btn_TouchDown;

        _MyCellView.AddSubview(btn);

    }

    private void Btn_TouchDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the click event of `Button` . The event name is

```
btn.TouchUpInside += Btn_TouchUpInside;
```

Event `TouchDown` will been called when you tap the button but not take back your finger .

Comment: first of all, thanks 
You are right, but it's not working even with TouchUpInside

Comment: Share your sample and I will test it on my side.